# How to recompile only changed parts of chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I built Chromium from the source code (`ninja -C out/Debug chrome`) and make sure it works. After I executed:

```
git pull
gclient sync
ninja -C out/Debug chrome
```

The build system actually starts to building all the parts of the project again. Is it possible to rebuild only the changed parts of chromium?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible as it doesn't know what has changed or hasn't changed, nor where to get the data that has already been compiled once or how it should compare the data. It would be pretty huge process to check if parts of the project has already been compiled once and what has been updated and hasn't. It would probably still have to go through the whole project to validate and then how's that different from just compiling it all? I could be wrong, but I don't think this sort of thing is possible in this case.

Comment: Thank you! But how then contributors works? Is it after each git pull rebuild the whole project? The compilation process takes me about 6 hours.

Comment: You could try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547371/speeding-up-chromium-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always do *release* build if you don't want to *debug* chrome browser.

Use `ninja -C out/Release chrome` to perform a release build. Debug build takes time in linking.

`git pull` updates your code and `gclient sync` syncs or sets the HEAD of the repo to the **L**ast **K**nown **G**ood **R**evision(LKGR). Hence, no. of changed files plus no. of files which were dependent on that would be *recompiled* again.

Answer (score 1):

From the [windows build instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Faster-builds) it lists this build parameter:

> `is_component_build = true` - this uses more, smaller DLLs, and incremental linking.

Execute:

```
gn args out/WhateverYouWant
```

Add

```
is_component_build = true
```

to the text file, save it, and close it.

For every build after the first it won't compile any components that you haven't changed.